# Tikz aligning matrix cells in different nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I overlap matrix cells in tikz relatively (using `m-2-2` instead of specifying the coordinates)?

[image: manual alignment]

This is the code I have for manual alignment:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node(m) at (0,0) [matrix,matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&] {1 \& 2\\3 \& abc\\};
    \node(n) at (12pt,-13pt) [matrix,matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&] {5 \& 6\\7 \& 8\\};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I tried some combos of below/above/anchors which didn't really work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \matrix[inner sep=0pt] (m) at (0,0) [matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&,nodes={inner sep=4pt}] {1 \& 2\\3 \& abc\\};
    \matrix[inner sep=0pt] (n) at (m-2-2.center) [matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&,anchor=n-1-1.center,nodes={inner sep=4pt}] {5 \& 6\\7 \& 8\\};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please study the code, ask for clarifications, if any. I got to rush now.

Comment: Ah!. Image gives trouble. Somebody please update the image.